# Start editing a TreeTableCell from a code request

Tags: javafx-8

I have a TreeTableView that is working great.  I have implemented a context menu that appears when the "TreeTableCell" is clicked.  In my context menu, I have a MenuItem called "edit" that, when selected, I want to cause the current TreeTableCell to start editing.  Unfortunately, I am unable to figure out how to correctly start editing the cell.

My initial thinking was that since the context menu callback is in the scope of my TreeTableCell instance, I would call the "startEdit" method of my cell.  This appears to work ... however, when the commitEdit occurs, I get a NullPointerException deep within the internals of JavaFX.  This makes me think that explicitly calling startEdit() is the wrong thinking and that there should be a correct way to cause a specific cell in the table to begin its edit cycle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to find the answer after lower level study.  I had assumed that I could call `startEdit()` against my `TreeTableCell` however that is *not* the correct way to flag a table cell as entering is editing mode.

Instead both TableView and TreeTableView expose an `edit()` method that take two parameters:

- The row number of the table indexed from 0
- The TableColumn of the table

The combination of row and column provide a unique location of a cell in the table.  Calling `edit()` places the cell in editing mode.

Here is the JavaDoc for TableView edit method:

[JavaDoc for TableView edit](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TableView.html#edit-int-javafx.scene.control.TableColumn-)